# C is the vector space of all convergent sequence with real entries. Prove that it is infinite dimensionsal.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I know the that the proof will revolve around proving a subspace of C to have infinite dimensions, but I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : Consider the sequences $u^k$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ where $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, u^k_n = 1$ for $k=n$ and $u^k_n = 0$ for $k \neq n$. Are they linearly independent? Do they converge?